# Errors while deploying app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, heroku-cli

I have been trying to deploy a nodejs app under appname 'picbookapp' on heroku which has a mongo database.For mongodb I have used mlabs and I have added MONGO_URI to the config vars in my heroku app.I have also added the Procfile file.But for some reasons I am getting errors.Since I am new to app deployment any kind of help would be highly appreciated.Here are the few error logs
**start: not found 
code ELIFECYCLE,
errrno ENOENT,file sh,
syscall spawn,
spawn ENOENT**
Here is the packag.json file--

```
{
  "name": "gridfsandmulter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Harshit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.4",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.30",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.4",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.1.1",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the database.js

```
/**
 * Created by harshitbisht96 on 30/7/17.
 */
var mongodb=require('mongodb');
var MongoClient=mongodb.MongoClient;
var url=process.env.MONGOLAB_URI||'mongodb://localhost:27017/imageDatabase';

function getDb(){
     return MongoClient.connect(url).then(function (db) {
        // console.log(MongoClient.connect(url));
        return db;
    })
}




module.exports=getDb();
```

Comment: Have you installed the heroku command line tools? What is `start`? Do you mean to use `node start.js` ?

Comment: Yes I have installed heroku command line tools.My bad it has to be "start":"node server.js".I edited that and tried again but still same errors.

Comment: Is it the exact same error? The errors in that screenshot are complaining that start isn't found so if it's the same error then that can't have fixed it.

Comment: Yes.Let me share the new screenshot

Comment: I think your question is not complete. But you can check the build logs on your Heroku dashboard. It will provide you with probable causes

Comment: It is working now.Thanks for help.It was only the "start" thing which I wrote wrong initially and a syntax error.Thanks for all help.